# C# Assigning items from params to variables based on class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, parameters

I have a problem, where I pass multiple items with different classes but the same parent class as params to a class constructor, and then assigning them to variables of the new class:

```
public class Tool {}
public class Hammer:Tool {}
public class Screwdriver:Tool{}
```

So my tool classes all inherit from the parent tool class. Now I want to create a toolbox, where I store my tools; however, I will not always want to make it with a full set of tools, so I pass a params with undefined number of parameters:

```
public class Toolbox{
public Hammer hammer;
public Screwdriver screwdriver;
public Toolbox(params Tool[] tool){
    foreach (Tool t in tool){
        switch (t.getType().Name){
            case "Hammer":
                hammer = t;
                break;
            case "Screwdriver":
                screwdriver = t;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the compiler to say that it "cannot implicitly convert 'Tool' to 'Hammer', but an explicit conversion is available".
What could be the problem in this situation and is it possible to fix in some easy way?

Comment: While you can easily cast t to Hammer like this (Hammer)t you should consider changing the argument list of your Toolbox constructor. The current one sounds like terrible design.

Comment: As an amateur C#-er: why is it a terrible design? I need to pass a lot of objects with the same parent class to the constructor. What would be a better approach?

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate between them? Couldn't you just have a list of Tools and each tool has its Use method that works in a different way?

Comment: btw if you want Stilgar to see your answer to his comment you need to write @HisName that way he gets notified you answered his comment.

Comment: I want them to have different parameters, and, design slots that can hold only that particular class of tool. Would a dictionary of parameters and a name parameter differentiation work better?

Comment: The coding stye looks like `Java` and not `C#`.

Comment: @Mee it seems like you need to pass a fixed number of Tools of specific types (in your example 1 Hammer and 1 Screwdriver) and not an arbitrary number of Tools of unknown derived type.

Comment: @Stilgar this is just a sample, in reality I will have toolbox with ~10 slots and not all of them will be filled.

Comment: @Mee You should ask a question that is closer to reality so we can answer properly. If you have 10 slots and a number of them are optional you either need to add the mandatory as separate parameters and the others as optional or use something like the Builder pattern. Hard to say without knowing more. However allowing the wrong type of parameters to be passed and cases like passing two screwdrivers only to use the last one are most probably wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are using a lot of `case/switch`, you should take it as a warning sign that you are not doing things the OO way.

The OO way to do this is to define a common property to `Tool` and use only that when choosing a slot. You then set the location in the descendant class, like so:

```
Enum Location { Big, Large, Small, Drawer, Hanging}

class Tool
{
    public abstract Location Location { get; }
}

class Hammer
{
    public override Location { get { return Location.Top; } }
}
```

Now your toolbox code is trivial:

```
class Toolbox
{
    public readonly List<Location,List<Tool>> Store = new List<Location,List<Tool>>();

    public Toolbox(params Tool[] tool)
    {
        foreach (Tool t in tool)
            this.Store[t.Location].Add(t);
    }
}
```

If you need more complexity than that, you can put the logic into the descendant class:

```
class Tool
{
    public abstract void StoreIn(Toolbox toolbox);
}

class Hammer
{
    public override void StoreIn(Toolbox toolbox)
    {
        toolbox.TopDrawer.Add(this);
    }
}
```

Again, your toolbox code is trivial:

```
class Toolbox
{
    public void AddTools(params Tool[] tool)
    {
        foreach (Tool t in tool) t.StoreIn(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, this looks really good, however I need to see if I can apply this to my situation, when this is a bit more complicated. It still looks way better than what I did.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that *you* know that its a `Hammer` but the compiler only knows it is a `Tool`. The way to solve this is, as the error message says, with an explicit conversion:

```
hammer = (Hammer)t;
```

With this cast you are telling the compiler that `t` is in fact a `Hammer`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? This cast operation can gives you your expected result. You can reach and use `derived class` properties

Edited answer and added @ja72 recomendation

```
foreach (Tool t in tool)
{
    // option 1
    if (t is Hammer)
    {
        Hammer hammer = t as Hammer;
        .....
    }

    // option 2 @ja72 recomendation
    if (t is Screwdriver screwdriver)
    {
        .......
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use C# pattern matching `if(t is Hammer hammer) { this.hammer = hammer; }`

Answer (score 0):

In modern C# this is how you check for types:

```
public class Toolbox
{
    readonly Hammer hammer;
    readonly Screwdriver screwdriver;
    public Toolbox(params Tool[] tool)
    {
        foreach (Tool t in tool)
        {
            if (t is Hammer hammer)
            {
                this.hammer = hammer;
            }
            if (t is Screwdriver screwdriver)
            {
                this.screwdriver = screwdriver;
            }
        }
    }
#region Properties       
    public Screwdriver Screwdriver => screwdriver;
    public Hammer Hammer => hammer;
    public bool HasHammer => hammer != null;
    public bool HasScrewdriver => screwdriver != null;
#end region
}
```

The construct `x is Hammer` is a boolean to test if `x` is of `Hammer` type. When used as `if(x is Hammer y) {  }` if `x` is a `Hammer` type, it will be referenced by the `y` variable within the scope of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your Toolbox class it seems that it can contain at most 1 Hammer and at most 1 Screwdriver. Let's ignore for the moment that you are defining the variables as public; you can gain practically identical effect with the following class definition:

```
public class Toolbox {
  public Hammer Hammer { get; set;}
  public Screwdriver Screwdriver { get; set;}
  public Toolbox() { }
}
```

Then instead of writing (assuming you have defined a variable with the name hammer):

```
Toolbox t = new Toolbox(hammer);
```

you can write:

```
Toolbox t = new Toolbox() { Hammer = hammer };
```

If you need to add other Tools you can just add new properties to the Toolbox class.